# Browsing specific identifier with OPC UA

Tags: java, eclipse, opc, milo

Dear stackoverflowers,

I tried to browse identifiers from the server(PLC) with OPC UA. The functionality in the Milo implementation presented how it should be done. Now I'm trying to, instead of browsing the whole ObjectsFolder, browse the attribute from **one** identifier.

How is this done?

Figure 1: Displays UaExpert client and the identifier I want to get.

Figure 2: Displays the Milo BrowseNodeExample.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes aren't browsed, they're read.

You already have the NodeId of the Node you're interested in, so now you invoke the Read service for the attributes you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin. Now, is it possible to read attributes by tag names (identifier)?

Comment: @LamarSt You need to have the NodeId to do pretty much anything in OPC UA. You might be able to infer the NodeId from the tag name depending on what PLC or server you're talking to, but you always need a NodeId.

Comment: Thank you very much Kevin. I'll continue testing.